# scala - process string parsed from gatling EL expression in place with anonymous function

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using Gatling EL expression in a http test, and it seems that wrapping the EL expression of any kind will invalidate the parsing, i.e.,

This works:

```
def run(env: Parameters): ChainBuilder =
  feed(env.feeder)
  .exec(
    http(Seq(env.env, "verify").mkString(":"))
      .get(env.base + "/verify")
      .queryParam("email", "${username}")
      .check(
        status.is(200),
        jsonPath("$..exist").is("true"),
      )
  )
  exitHereIfFailed
```

But this does not work:

```
def run(env: Parameters): ChainBuilder =
  feed(env.feeder).exec(
    http(Seq(env.base, "authorize").mkString(":"))
      .post(env.base + "/authorize")
      .asJSON // "Accept" and "ContentType" set to JSON
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.AcceptCharset, "UTF-8")
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.Authorization,
        "AppBasic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("${username}" + ":" + "password").getBytes())))
      .body(StringBody(env.authorizeBody))
      .check(
        status.is(200),
        header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType).is(HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson),
        header(HttpHeaderNames.AcceptCharset).is("UTF-8"),
        jsonPath("$..id_token") exists
    )
  )
```

I want to encode with Base64 "email:password" and use it as Authorization header, with "AppBasic" as prefix. So it is not `Basic` authorization, which has `Basic` as prefix.

Now I do something like:

```
...
.header(HttpHeaderNames.Authorization,
      "AppBasic " + "${username}".map(username => Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + "password").getBytes())))
...
```

But, the log shows a strange `Vector`. I want a `String`.

```
HTTP request:
POST <some url>
headers=
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: AppBasic Vector(JDoxMTEx, ezoxMTEx, dToxMTEx, czoxMTEx, ZToxMTEx, cjoxMTEx, bjoxMTEx, YToxMTEx, bToxMTEx, ZToxMTEx, fToxMTEx)
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Content-Length: 143
```

So, it is a in-place string conversion, not a collection mapping. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a Gatling problem, than a Scala problem, but let's try to find out what's going on here.

### Scala String Interpolation

To include values into a string one can use String Interpolation using the `${…}` syntax. Example:

`s"Hello, $name"` where `name = "World"` would result in `"Hello World`. However, that is **not** what you are using.

Now the easiest thing to do would be to actually use this instead. However it would require the value of `username` to be available in the scala program.

If I see it correctly, you want the value to come from the Gatling Session and thus are using the [Gatling Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/), as you already mentioned.

If that is not the case, the easiest thing to do would be to use Scala String interpolation:

```
def asBase64(input: String): String = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input.getBytes())
val username = "johnDoe"
val password = "1111" // Some more or less random password
val headerValue = asBase64(s"${username}:$password")
val header = s"Basic $headerValue" // … should be "Basic am9obkRvZToxMTEx" here
```

### What's happening here?

> **Gatling parses Strings parameter values** and turn them into functions that will compute a result based on the data stored into the Session when they will be evaluated.

(taken from the documentation with the highlight from me)
This requires that the string is passed to Gatling. However you are using plain Scala here to transform the String.
Gatling is an embedded DSL, meaning it is embedded in the host language (Scala) and this just bit you.

You are doing this

```
"${username}".map(username =>
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + "password").getBytes()
```

Let's go through this step by step:
`${username}` is **not** String interpolation like above, because it is missing the "string interpolation methods" at the beginning (e.g. the `s` in `s""`) which is correct, if you want to pass it literally for it to be parsed by Gatling.
However you don't pass it into Gatling, instead you are `map` over it.
This is plain Scala and Scala has no idea of something like a `Session` where values are within.

Instead `String.map` passes each character and uses the function on it.
What you thought would be the `username` is actually a single *letter*.

So it goes on and uses `username + ":" + "password"` on each letter.
By the way: Your original code didn't had `"password"` there… and if that is a real hidden password, it isn't hidden anymore (Base64 is reversable).

So this is where the

```
Vector(JDoxMTEx, ezoxMTEx, dToxMTEx, czoxMTEx, ZToxMTEx, cjoxMTEx, bjoxMTEx, YToxMTEx, bToxMTEx, ZToxMTEx, fToxMTEx)
```

comes from. It has 11 entries, one for each letter in: `$, {, u, s, e, r, n, a, m, e, }` combined with a bit more.

### What can be done instead to use a password from the session

The easiest thing would be to use what [Gatling already offers](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#authentication). These don't know about your `AppBasic` and will use `Basic` instead… so no option.

You could use the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/#getting-attributes) to access the value (with `session("name")` accessing the value from the session).

```
.header(HttpHeaderNames.Authorization, s"AppBasic ${asBase64(s"${session("username").as[String]}:$password")}")
```

which assumes, that the function `asBase64` is defined like above (otherwise it's a bit longer) and that there is a variable `password` in scope.
If not just replace it (along with the dollar) with the value you want there.

So hopefully this helps you with your problem.
I would say that you are not fully aware of what is Gatling specific and what is Scala (which is totally okay, but sometimes it will bite you, like here). I went to a bit of length in the hope that this separates it a bit.

Your basic problem was that you were used to access values from a session with the dollar notation. Which is fine as long as you are passing values to Gatling. In this case Gatling does this for you. However it won't work in plain Scala, there you have to access them using the Session API. You can see if you can access a value with the dollar notation, if the API talks about an `Expression[…]` which means that Gatling takes an extra turn to parse it (which is exactly why it knows that there is a reference in it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But the solution I think is not using scala interpolation here, because when I apply your suggestion, `"AppBasic ${asBase64(s"` is truncated as a string and the rest is ignored, thus compilation error. I have read another similar question with exact same situation and it is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439235/using-a-feeder-to-pass-in-header-values-gatling. I followed that and it works. Thanks again. I think `session` is not directly available inside the chain; I had `cannot find symbol session` error too.  We have to construct a function.

Comment: The second `"` is inside the `${}` expression and should not terminate the outer string expression. I just double checked that this works. However you're right with the function: `session` needs to be passed in for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer from another question:

[Using a feeder to pass in header values (Gatling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439235/using-a-feeder-to-pass-in-header-values-gatling)

The solution is to write a function here, in my case:

```
.header(HttpHeaderNames.Authorization, session =>
    for {
        username <- session("username").validate[String]
    } yield "AppBasic " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString((username + ":" + "1111").getBytes())
)
```

Thanks for that.

Before found this I have done a workaround: the team leader replace the 10k lines test csv with a 20 lines one, because Gatling will load beforehand the content into memory in testing, and have a big csv will consume memory, as per documentation.

So with 20 lines I can hardcode the encoded email:password in the csv file and read them with column name "${col_name}".

But it is best to read from session. I didn't know that. Thanks @tilois.